# css: override active link style?

Tags: css

i have the following selector in my css:

```
a:active {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
}
```

So every link has this little button-effect when it's pressed.

How can i prevent that behaviour for specific links?

e.g. i have a "back to top" link on my website that shouldn't have this behaviour.

```
a#back-to-top {
    position:fixed;
    right:0px;
    bottom:20px;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    background:green;
}
```

In this case the "back-to-top" starts to jump. 
However if I try to reset this it doesn't work.

```
a#back-to-top:active  {
    position:fixed !important;
    bottom:20px !important;
}
```

any idea what I'm doing wrong or how I could exclude specific links from that active behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try resetting the `top` property as well.

```
a#back-to-top:active  {
    position: fixed !important;
    top: auto !important;
}
```

Comment: but his non active styling sets the position to fixed for the `#back-to-top` element.

Comment: you also do not need the `!important` since the rule has higher specificity, and also the `bottom` since it is not overridden by the generic `a` rule.

Comment: @Gaby Yeah, I was just leaving them there because the OP had them in their example. Your answer already explains all that :)

Comment: thank you. didn't need the !important rules like Gaby says. perfect. Thank both of you.

Answer (score 2):

The following

```
a#back-to-top:active {
  position:fixed;
  top: auto;
}
```

would fix it, since it is more specific and will get applied, and it overrides the part that makes your button move..

No need for the `!important` directive since the rule has higher specificity and will get applied instead..

**demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/zUEER/

Answer (score 0):

i think you should "reset" the top decleration

```
a#back-to-top:active  {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:20px;
    top: auto;
}
```

also, use !important only if for some reason the a#back-to-top:active style declartion comes before a:active one.

Comment: it doesn't matter if it comes after or before the `a:active` one because it has higher specificity due to the id, so it will always be the one applied.